# mysql inserting into 2 tables at once that have primary key and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have two tables

**books table**

- ID (PK)
- Title
- Author
- Genre
- ISBN
- Price
- publisher
- Year

**bookAwards table**

- ID (FK) -- referencing Books.ID
- Awardname
- Year

ID of bookAwards is foreign key of ID in books table.

How can I insert into books table at the same time into bookAwards table?

When I am trying to insert into books table it gives the error that foreign key causes?

I want to insert into books table the values and then an awardname with a year into bookAwards?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STORED PROCEDURE` on this so you will only call once from the application level. Example,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertBook
(
    IN _Title INT,
    IN _AwardName VARCHAR(35),
    IN _Year INT
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Books (Title)
    VALUES(_Title);

    -- since the ID is set as AUTO_INCREMENT
    -- there are two ways to do how you can get the ID 
    -- from the Books Table and insert it 
    -- on BookAwards

    -- FIRST WAY
    -- by using LAST_INSERT_ID()
    SET @last_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    -- SECOND WAY
    -- by using MAX()
    -- SET @last_ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Books);


    INSERT INTO BookAwards(ID, AwardName, Year)
    VALUES (@last_ID, _AwardName, _Year);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And on the application level or on any sources that you want to call this procedure,

```
CALL InsertBook('Lost Art', 'Best in Churva', 2013);
```

For security purposes, you can still parameterized the procedure, eg

```
CALL InsertBook(?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: is there an easier way of doing it ? I am using php with mysql. I have an admin interface for an elibrary. So what I am trying to do is that when admin wants to add a book to the catalog page, he puts values in the text boxes then I get the values in the text boxes and inset them into those tables. Should I run the Procedure in the mysql database and then I call the procedure in the php script ?

Comment: what do you mean easier? execute two `INSERT` statement. rather than wrapping it on stored procecure.

Comment: sorry for some reason when I hold shift and enter instead of going to a new line it submits the comment I was trying to type more but it got submitted that's why my question was looking so general.

Comment: you can call the procedure in the php script. instead of writing `INSERT INTO..` statement, use `CALL InsertBook(...)`

Comment: #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' I got this error when I tried your example.

Comment: please post the result of this two statements along with your question, `DESC Books` and `DESC BookAwards` are there any incrementing columns?

Comment: yes the books ID and bookAwards ID are both set to auto increment