# How to insert into multiple tables using auto increment value for remaining tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with 2 tables for example. The first table (table1) has:

```
  userId int not null auto_increment primary key
  userEmail
  userPassword
```

The userId is my primary key which is auto incremented. My next table (table2) has:

```
 userProfileId int not null auto_increment primary key
 userAge
 userGender
 userId
```

The userId (from table2) is my foreign key that references table1(userId). Is there a way to INSERT INTO all information for both tables and have the userId in table2 automatically get the primary key that it references from table1? Or do I have to do multiple INSERTS for each table and explicitly make my foreign key the same value.

Comment: If i am not wrong you want to insert into both the tables at once right ? For this you can create a procedure. have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725630/mysql-inserting-into-2-tables-at-once-that-have-primary-key-and-forign-key

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Last_insert_id" of mysql like below-

```
<?php
$user_query="INSERT INTO accounts (userId,userEmail,userPassword) VALUES (NULL,'saving@gmail.com','XXXXXXXXX')";
$profile_query="INSERT INTO transactions(userProfileId,userAge,userGender,userId) VALUES (NULL,25,'m'LAST_INSERT_ID)";

$a_query=mysql_query($user_query);
$t_query=mysql_query($profile_query);
?>
```

Note: mysql_* are deprecated. Instead you can use PDO statements.

Reff : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Reff : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. However, if i had multiple threads writing and pulling from my database how would i stop from getting incorrect foreign keys if i had 2 simultaneous writes?

Comment: You can lock the table than.

Comment: I know this is old, but for the benefit of anyone reading, an easier way to do that without locking the table if you are using mysqli is: $db->query("INSERT INTO accounts (userId,userEmail,userPassword) VALUES (NULL,'saving@gmail.com','XXXXXXXXX')"); $db->query("INSERT INTO transactions(userProfileId,userAge,userGender,userId) VALUES (NULL,25,'m',".(int)$db->insert_id.")");